# Need Help on Tcl RegExp

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to match a pattern like the following shown below, it's an environment variable followed by a directory name. I want to match it exactly both the words. If it does match return 1.

```
$::env(WORK)/bill/
```

How can this be done in TCL using *regexp*?
I am newbie so any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

I have tried it with this and it works:

```
if {![file isdirectory "${::env(WORK)}/bill/"]} {} else { return 1}
```

With RE:
regexp {^(bill)$} for the second word . First word since it is environment variable I get stuck there

Comment: I have tried it with this and it works:    if {![file isdirectory "${::env(WORK)}/bill/"]} {} else {
return 1} However I want to try it with regexp

Comment: regexp {^(bill)$} for the second word . First word since it is environment variable I get stuck there

Comment: Since you already had something that works, is there a reason why you need regexp?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand your question. You have a Tcl string and you want to match a pattern `$::env(something)/somethingelse/` identifying the `something` and the `somethingelse` part.

If it is so, then you want to use somethink like

```
set str {$::env(WORK)/bill/}
if {[regexp {\$::env\((.+)\)/(.+)/} $string -> envName dirName]} {
    puts $envName
    puts $dirName
}
```

and you should have

```
WORK
bill
```

printed on your terminal.

In the `regexp` command, the pattern is included in `{}` to avoid Tcl substitutions. It starts with an escaped dollar `\$` because the dollar would match an end of a line. Then a literal `::env` follows. Then escaped parentheses `\(...\)` to match the array syntax. Insede them, we have a capturing atom `(.+)` for matching any character repeated one or more times, with reporting. Then follows literals slashes `/.../` with a second capturing atom `(.+)` for matching the directory part.

The `->` is the name of a variable which will contain everything in `$str` that matches the pattern (you can see it by printing it with `puts ${->}`), but it's not needed in this case, so we use the strange name.

Then two var names follows, `envName` and `dirName`, which will report respectively the match of the first and the second atom `(.+)` (parentheses excluded).

**Edit** For non-greedy matching, as pointed out by Donal Fellows, you can use `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)`, and I agree it would be a nice add.

I hope this answers your needs.

Comment: It probably ought to be using non-greedy REs or suitable negated sets (so that you don't get surprised by the case where there are correct match points in the input string). Otherwise, this looks like a very reasonable approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Marco Pallante

Comment: Hi, Solution provided by Pallante does work but when you literally want to match $::env(WORK) as is. But in my case the $::env(WORK) is actually an environment variable that opens up to a following path. So, I would want when I do regular expression matching then at that time the whole path be substituted.  For example setenv WORK /tmp/somedir/somedir/. When i do puts on $::WORK I get $> /tmp/somedir/somedir on Tcl prompt.

Comment: @arkanoid That is sufficiently different from your original question that you should ask a new question. That's OK. Be very specific in your new question about what you are starting from, what you want to get to, what variation in the values you expect (important for REs) and what you have already tried yourself to get to a solution before getting stuck. You probably ought to also link to this question (but make sure you're not asking the same thing!)